# "The meeting" denotes people or an event?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition, dictionaries, error

In the following sentence, does "the meeting" refer to an event or the people participating in the event?

> The meeting broke up at eleven o'clock.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary has the following definition for "break up":

to go away in different directions

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/break-up_1?q=break+up

It sounds as if the event we call "the meeting" went away in different directions!

I thought it was the **people** who had participated in a meeting that went away.

Please note the the thread is **NOT** about whether the phrasal verb "break up" collocates with "meeting." Rather, it is about whether there is a **mismatch** between **definition** and the example sentence.

Somehow many native speakers don't know what is at issue. **Although the said dictionary does include the "come to an end" definition, this move hardly justifies the **mismatch** between the example sentence in question and the "to go away in different directions" definition.**

Comment: The dictionary is telling you what this means. It is an idiomatic way of saying that something organised has ceased. In British English, we also say that schools 'break up' when they close for a break between terms. I'm not sure this is so much a question as an exclamation that you think it sounds like something else.

Comment: @Astralbee The issue is NOT whether "The meeting broke up" is idiomatic. It is. The issue is whether "the meeting went away in different directions" makes sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be based on a quibble.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So you think "the meeting" went away in different directions" makes perfect sense?

Comment: As I said, Oxford Languages refers to a gathering dispersing, implying that the _people who attended_ 'go away in different  directions'. Language doesn't have to be exactly literal if the meaning is clear.

Comment: @KateBunting But lexicographical work is supposed to be rigorous.

Comment: Other dictionaries give better definitions such as "come to an end."

Comment: And I am criticizing Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, not other Oxford dictionaries.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, there's the sense "to come to an end." That serves to show that the example sentence "The meeting broke up at eleven o'clock" should have been placed under that sense, not under the "to go away in different directions" sense.

Comment: @KateBunting Dictionary definitions often employ the label "(of X)" to indicate the subject of a particular verb or the set of entities that an adjective modifies. Granted, common sense dictates that it is the meeting's participants that go away in different directions. But that fact is supposed to be encoded in the definition. A definition that fails to do that is inadequate.

Comment: @KateBunting Better definitions also employ other techniques to address issues like the one in hand. For example, the Collins Cobuild Dictionary uses the phrasing: "When a meeting or gathering breaks up or when someone breaks it up, it is brought to an end and the people involved in it leave. "

Comment: @Apollyon My mistake and apologies! I've restored your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the meeting can't break up. It's the people participating in the meeting! In different contexts things can mean different things, **especially** this case.

"break-up":

> (of a gathering) come to an end and disperse. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/break_up)

So the **people** in the meeting dispersed, not the event dispersing.

Comment: I was shocked to find editors for the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary should be so imprecise in their phrasing.

Comment: There's nothing 'imprecise' about the dictionary's phrasing. Meetings break up. So do schools. Courts rise. Parliaments dissolve. Subtleties of this type are best resolved by finding other, more advanced reference material than a learner's dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have no problem with "meetings break up." What I find problematic is the Oxford Advanced Learner's **definition**. That's certainly an instance of imprecise phrasing.

Comment: Meetings certainly break up, but do meetings "go away in different directions"?

Comment: @Apollyon - the meeting, in the sense of something that can break up, is understood to include the meaning of 'the people attending the meeting'. When the meeting ended, the people attending left the table, or room, and went to different places. They must, necessarily, have gone in 'different directions'. If they all went in exactly the same direction at exactly the same time, they would run the risk of treading on each other's feet, which would not be seemly or business-like. All these things are understood, but not explicitly and rigorously explained in a learner's dictionary.

Comment: @Apollyon meetings cannot go away in different directions, people can

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Dictionary definitions often employ the label "(of X)" to indicate the subject of a particular verb or the set of entities that an adjective modifies. Granted, common sense dictates that it is the meeting's participants that go away in different directions. But that fact is supposed to be encoded in the definition. A definition that fails to do that is inadequate.

Comment: Better definitions also employ other techniques to address issues like the one in hand. For example, the Collins Cobuild Dictionary uses the phrasing: "When a meeting or gathering breaks up or when someone breaks it up, it is brought to an end and the people involved in it leave. "